# How to dynamically map a database table in Golang?

Tags: go, dynamic, struct

I have to create a JSON from  a MS-SQL Database through Go. The problem is that some database fields are created dynamically in backend system (not Go).

There could be:

```
type Demotable struct{
Id int
Name string
Adress int
Z_somedynamicfield string
Z_anotherfield int
}
```

All fields prefixed with "Z_" are dynamic, so struct could also be:

```
type Demotable struct{
Id int
Name string
Adress int
Z_completedifferent int
Z_notlikefirst string
Z_evenmorefields string
}
```

I also have a helper table where every "dynamic field" is described:

```
| tableName | fieldName          | fieldType |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| Demotable | Z_somedynamicfield | string    |
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| Demotable | Z_anotherfield     | int       |
...
```

Ideally I would dynamically "extend" struct with infos from helper table - but I don't have an idea how or if this even is possible?

Comment: You cannot extend structs at runtime. You'll have to build a map that you can then JSON encode. sql.Rows.Columns and .ColumnTypes return column names and types of a result set, respectively. You shouldn't need to query that other table.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugges first querying the current tables of your table through a prepared statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'MyTable'
```

Store the results of the query in a string slice. After doing so, create a map with `string` keys and `*interface{}` values.

```
 results := make(map[string](*interface{})
```

While iterating over results of your actual query, you can finally assign the values from your previous query to map the results.

Kyle Banks offers a great explanation on receiving dynamic results from Query results on [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/query-result-to-map-in-golang) article.

If for any reason you need to actually specify the type of the results, the [`reflect` package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) will be of a lot of help on auto-resolving the value type for your needs.